# Remove newline character before whitespace in R

Tags: r, regex, newline

I want to remove the newline character if the next line begins with a space or a tab in R.
So far I have tried using regex:

```
text <- gsub("\n(?=\\h)","",x,perl=True)
```

but that didn't work

Comment: I removed the `perl` tag, since the question is obviously targeted for `r`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
text <- gsub("\\R(?=\\h)", "", x, perl=TRUE)
```

The `\R(?=\h)` pattern matches any line break sequence (matched with `\R`) before any horizontal whitespace (checked for presence with a `(?=\h)` positive lookahead).

See an [R demo](https://rextester.com/IXOWO88708):

```
x <- "Line 1\r\n coninuation of line 1\r\nLine 2"
gsub("\\R(?=\\h)", "", x, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] "Line 1 coninuation of line 1\r\nLine 2"
```

Comment: This solution is especially nice since from what I understand it is platform-independent, which is relevant here because line breaks could be represented differently on Windows and Unix-based OS's.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `TRUE` instead of `True` in `R`

```
gsub("\n(?=\\h)","",x,perl=TRUE)
```

Comment: Perhaps `"\r?\n(?=\\h)"` to also remove carriage returns.